# how do i store prize bond numbers in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

i am creating a site in which i want to add the functionality for checking prize bond numbers 
but i am confused how do i store the prize bond numbers in database so the way i am doing it is as flows

i created a table named prizebond with these fields

```
id, prizebond_price, prizebond_date, prizebond_numbers
```

now should insert all prizebond numbers in `prizebond_numbers` row , i mean there is 200+ prize bond numbers is it right to insert them all in single row or is there any other good way that i can do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data like:

- Table1 `id, prizebond_price, prizebond_date`
- Table2 `prizebond_id,prizebond_number` (`prizebond_id` points to `id` field in Table1)

Comment: can i insert all prize bond number in single column prizebond_numbers?

Comment: you can but its not recommended since it will be very hard for you to update the contents and for other reasons , the best way is to keep prizebond_numbers in a different table like i suggested